# Evaluating $\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt[4]{\ln(12-x^2)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

> Find Derivative and evaluate at $x=1$:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt[4]{\ln(12-x^2)} = (\ln u)^{1/4}
$$

$$v=(v)^{1/4} \implies v=\ln\;u, v\;'=\dfrac{1}{u}(u\;')$$

$$y\;'=\frac{1}{4}v^{-3/4}\; \times v\;'= \dfrac{1}{4}\dfrac{1}{v^{3/4}}v\;'$$

$$\frac{1}{4} \dfrac{1}{\ln(12-x^2)^{3/4}} \dfrac{1}{\ln(12-x^2)} (-2x)$$

Is this correct? It doesn't look correct. I evaluated at $1$ and got $-0.10821.$

Comment: You've got an extra "$\ln$".  You need $\dfrac{1}{12-x^2}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\big (\sqrt[4]{\ln(12-x^2)}\big)'\big|_{x=1}
=\frac 14(\ln(12-x^2))^{-\frac34}\frac{1}{12-x^2}(-2x)\big|_{x=1}=-\frac{(\ln 11)^{-\frac34}}{22}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You did not calculate the derivative of $\ln(12-x^2)$ correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It is not correct, but you are really close: you miscalculated the derivative of $\log(12 - x^2)$, which should be just $\frac{1}{12 - x^2} \cdot (-2x)$.

Answer (score 1):

The secret:
Applying the chain rule
until it stops hurting.

Reminder:
$(f(g(x)))'
=g'(x)f'(g(x))
$.
Also
$(\ln f(x))'
=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}
$
and
$(f(x)^a)'
=f'(x)f(x)^{a-1}
$

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{d}{dx}\sqrt[4]{\ln(12-x^2)}
&=((\ln(12-x^2))^{1/4})'\\
&=(\ln(12-x^2))'(\ln(12-x^2))^{-3/4}\\
&=\dfrac{(12-x^2)'}{12-x^2}(\ln(12-x^2))^{-3/4}\\
&=\dfrac{-2x}{12-x^2}(\ln(12-x^2))^{-3/4}\\
\end{array}
$